# How to detect an enter key press in oracle forms 10g? distinguish netween tab key press and enter?

Tags: oracle, forms, oracleforms

i need to differentiate between an enter key press and tab key press in oracle forms. how can i do this without using java beans in 10g?
i have tried with key-enter trigger in block level and item level, but not working.
is there any way to accomplish this in oracle forms 10 g?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle forms uses mapping to see what key in java compares with a function in oracle forms. These mappings are in res-files (resource files).
If you change the res-files or in the formsweb.cfg file (config file for oracle forms can also be accessed from the enterprise manager) you can change the term variable and set him to use your own res-file.

In this file you can map the enter key and tab key to a different function.
More info on this topic:
[Enable key mappings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14032/configure011.htm)